# Drag and drop in QTreeView, removeRows not called

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have some problem with drag and drop in `QTreeView`:

I set flag to `Qt::MoveAction` and reimplemented `removeRows()`, `dropMimeData()` and etc in my model. The Model inherits `QAbstractItemModel`.

When I drag and drop, `mimeData()`, `dropMimeData()` are called automatically, 
and also `dropMimeData()` calls `insertRows()` automatcally. But `removeRows()` is not called, so the dragged item is still alive. I googled, but they said their `removeRows()` was called automatically.

- Why isn't my `removeRows()` called after `dropMimeData()`?
- Shoud I call `removeRows()` manually in `dropMimeData()`?
- If so, how can I know the previous `QModelIndex` of start of drag?

When starting drag, in `mimeData()`, I can save index in private member, but it looks like not good.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think yes, you have to call `removeRows()` from the `dropMimeData()` if the `Qt::DropAction` is `Qt::MoveAction`, i.e. you completely move your tree node from one place to another.

WRT your second question, you can create your custom mime data in `QAbstractItemModel::mimeData()` and encode your dragged nodes initial information there. So, in `dropMimeData()` function you can decode and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I know encode/decode custom mime data, but I couldn't encode the index of dragged node.. How can I encode the model index to QDataStream?

Comment: @user18640, For example, you can store the row and column numbers, or tree item path or any other information that can uniquely identify model index.

Comment: I see, I would encode row, column and modelindex internalid to use QAbstractItemModel::createIndex() in dropMimeData(). Thank you .

Comment: What if drag an drop performing between two different models? 'removeRows' actually should be called on source model. Documentation says that 'removeRows' will be called automatically, when 'dropMimeData' returns true.

Comment: This is wrong, Qt will automatically call `removeRows` for you when you return `true` from `dropMimeData()`

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

If everything is correctly configured, the target should not remove the source item, the initiator of the drag should remove the source item if a `Qt::MoveAction` is performed.

**Configuration of the view**

[`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) (which is the base class of `QTreeView`, `QListView`, `QTableView`, ...) implements the initiation and finishing of the [`QDrag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html) operation in [`startDrag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#startDrag):

> ```
> if (drag->exec(supportedActions, defaultDropAction) == Qt::MoveAction)
>     d->clearOrRemove();
> ```

So, when the requested drop action (returned by [`QDrag::exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#exec-1)) is a `Qt::MoveAction`, the item is automatically removed (or cleared as specified by `setDragDropOverwriteMode`).

Important configuration options of the view are:

- [`setDragDropMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropMode-prop): specifies if the view should accept drag and/or drop items from external or only internal items. This function calls `setDragEnabled` and `setAcceptDrops` accordingly.

  - [`setDragEnabled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragEnabled-prop): enables the builtin drag mechanism
  - [`setAcceptDrops`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop): enables the builtin drop mechanism
- [`setDragDropOverwriteMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropMode-prop): specifies if the source item should be removed (typical in a tree view) or cleared (typical in a table view)
- [`setDefaultDropAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#defaultDropAction-prop): the default drop action specified when initiating the `QDrag` operation.

**Configuration of the model**

Besides the configuration of the view, you should configure your model correctly.

- You should implement the *editing interface* of your model, i.e. `removeRows`, `insertRows`, `moveRows` and `setData`. Although it may not be necessary to implement all of them depending on your specific situation, it is a good approach to implement them anyway for an editable model.
- [`supportedDropActions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#supportedDropActions): Reimplement this function to return the support drop actions (`Qt::CopyAction` by default). Note that the user may switch between the different supported actions by pressing some keys. (`shift` for `Qt::MoveAction` and `control` for `Qt::CopyAction`)

  - [`supportedDragActions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#supportedDragActions): Reimplement this function if the supported drag actions are different from the supported drop actions.

**Examples**

Good examples are the source code of Qt itself. The corresponding `Q*Widget` classes (ex. `QTreeWidget` for `QTreeView`) are provides concrete implementations of the view and a corresponding model.

Comment: Another thing I've run into: The [`selectionBehavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) of the view must be set to `QAbstractItemView::SelectRows` (and **not** to `QAbstractItemView::SelectItems`).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my custom model. Setting `dragDropOverwriteMode=false` for view resolved my problem.

Comment: The default value for dragDropOverwriteMode is false, as in the QListView and QTreeView subclasses. In the QTableView subclass, on the other hand, the property has been set to true